# How to discard old toast notifications without closing push channel?

Tags: windows-phone-8, push-notification, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, mpns

According to MSDN, MPNS will put the notification requests in queue for delivery, so there is always time delay for them to get to device. My problem is that, sometimes, for example when the device goes to Temp Disconnected mode, the time delay is so long that the toast notifications become outdated when they arrive. Is there a way to discard/ignore these old toast notifications without renew the current push channel?  If not, is it all right for me to renew push channel every time I open app?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's OK to renew the channel every time you open the app. If your app is not running and you don't have a background task getting these notifications, you will automatically be discarding them anyway. Also, if my memory serves me correctly, should you use the channel request with an object that has been previously used to receive stuff from the channel, you can get the same channel (I might be wrong here). In this case, if you get old messages, you probably have to handle the local discarding manually.

Comment: Hi Muhwu, could you give me some links that talk about renewing channel every time app starts or how to deal with situations like mine?

Comment: how to use background task for this? pls advice.